# Series Override in Grafana for stacked bar

Tags: grafana

I created the following figure in Grafana. How do I **stack** all `Maint` into one bar, all `Rescu` into one bar and all `Accid` into one bar? What's the correct alias/regex for the `Series Overrides` part? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `/Maint/` - you can see regexp match example in the help provided by question mark symbol:

[image]

Comment: You need X-axis mode: Time, otherwise stacking doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

As Jan Garaj said, need to use `"/"` instead of `"["` and put `"Legend"` you have used.